# How to manage linked objects in complex scene?

Tags: linked-data

For example i have many scenes , one object may object-linked to object from other scene while other may only data-linked. How can i manage which object linked to which one in what scenes ? and how can i know is it data-linked or object linked ? things get complicated when there's many scenes. Is there any easy way to manage this or how to view this relationship ? something like relationship map maybe ?